# Tensorflow: Classifying images in batches

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing

I have followed [this TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) to classify images using transfer learning approach. Using almost 16,000 manually classified images (with about 40/60 split of 1/0) added on top of the pre-trained MobileNet V2 model, my model achieved 96% accuracy on the hold out test set. I then saved the resulting model.

Next, I would like to use this trained model to classify *new* images. To do so, I have adapted one of the portions of the tutorial's code (in the end where it says *#Retrieve a batch of images from the test set*) in the way described below. The code works, however, it only processes one batch of 32 images and that's it (there are hundreds of images in the source folder). What am I missing here? Please advise.

```
# Import libraries
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image_dataset_from_directory
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

# Load saved model
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('/model')

# Re-compile model
base_learning_rate = 0.0001
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=base_learning_rate),
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
# Define paths
PATH = 'Data/'             
new_dir = os.path.join(PATH, 'New_images') # New_images must contain at least one class (sub-folder)

IMG_SIZE = (640, 640)
BATCH_SIZE = 32

new_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(new_dir, shuffle=True, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, image_size=IMG_SIZE)

# Retrieve a batch of images from the test set
image_batch, label_batch = new_dataset.as_numpy_iterator().next()
predictions = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch).flatten()

# Apply a sigmoid since our model returns logits
predictions = tf.nn.sigmoid(predictions)
predictions = tf.where(predictions < 0.5, 0, 1)

print('Predictions:\n', predictions.numpy())
len(new_dataset) # equals 25, i.e., there are 25 batches
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this code:

```
# Retrieve a batch of images from the test set
image_batch, label_batch = new_dataset.as_numpy_iterator().next()
predictions = model.predict_on_batch(image_batch).flatten()
```

with this one:

```
predictions = model.predict(new_dataset,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE).flatten()
```

`tf.data.Dataset` objects can be directly passed to the method `predict()`. [Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate#training_evaluation_from_tfdata_datasets)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, @kindustrii I tried the suggested approach, however, it still gives me a small number of predictions when I run predict (output: <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>)

Comment: I will edit my answer, because i didn't realized that you're using the `model.predict_from_batch()` method. This method returns predictions just for a single batch of samples.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your solution has worked.